# Summing first 2 elements in a Python list when the length of the list is unknown

Tags: python, arrays, list, sum, conditional-statements

I am working on the following Python list exercise from codingbat.com:

> Given an array of ints, return the sum of the first 2 elements in the
>   array. If the array length is less than 2, just sum up the elements
>   that exist, returning 0 if the array is length 0.    Examples:
>
> ```
> sum2([1, 2, 3]) → 3 
>
> sum2([1, 1]) → 2
>
> sum2([1, 1, 1, 1]) → 2
> ```

My solution below works:

```
def sum2(nums):
  if len(nums)>=2:
    return nums[0] + nums[1]
  elif len(nums)==1:
    return nums[0]
  return 0
```

But I wonder if there's any way to solve the problem with fewer conditional statements.

Comment: `return sum(nums[:2])`?

Comment: +1 as it is same solution as answer accepted

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is.  Two elements of the solution - builtin function [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) and lists's [slices](http://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/):

```
>>> sum([1,2,3][:2])
3
>>> sum([1,1,1,1][:2])
2
>>> sum([1,1][:2])
2
>>> sum([1][:2])
1
>>> sum([][:2])
0
```

Comment: Those aren't "ranges", they're "slices".

Comment: @jonrsharpe That is true, was remembering the right term.

Comment: why do I have to wait 10 minutes to accept the answer?

Comment: @MyCarta to make sure you have time to review all the answers that pop up in that time

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use sum, one possible solution uses exceptions:

```
totalsum = 0
try:
  totalsum += nums[0]
  totalsum += nums[1]
except IndexError:
  pass
return totalsum
```

Catch the error and short-circuit the summation if an element doesn't exist. Easier to ask forgiveness than permission, as they say.

Comment: Better to use `except IndexError` - a "naked" `except` can catch all kinds of other things (e.g. a `TypeError` because `nums` can't be indexed at all or doesn't only contain numbers).

Comment: Cannot use it because the exercise is structured so that I have to use sum but very interesting, did not know anything exceptions, thank you.

Comment: @MyCarta your first answer wasn't using `sum`! [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-eafp) is a common Python coding style, worth being aware of.

Comment: OK I tried the code suggested by @TheSoundDefense and it works. Really interesting and I agree worth learning. I could've choosen either answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
def sum2(nums):
  if len(nums) == 1:
    return nums[0]
  else:
    return sum(nums [:2])
```