# Creating code to make sum of array elements with variable

Tags: python, list, sum

I want to create a code that has the variable how many elements you take from an list and sum those. For example, if I type in 3, it takes the first 3 elements of an array and addes them together.

Preferably in some for loop but who knows what kind of creative solutions I get :)

```
x = [1, 3, 4, 2, 6, 9, 4]

Amount = 3

Sum = 0
Sum += x[Amount-3] + x[Amount-2] + x[Amount-1]
```

Desired result: 8

```
Amount_2 = 4

Sum = 0
Sum += x[Amount-4] + x[Amount-3] + x[Amount-2] + x[Amount-1]
```

Desired result: 11

Hope this explains it well.

Comment: `Sum = sum(x[:Amount])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Summing first 2 elements in a Python list when the length of the list is unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24826842/summing-first-2-elements-in-a-python-list-when-the-length-of-the-list-is-unknown)

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [2, 6, 7, 7, 12]  # your list here
amount = int(input("Enter amount: "))
print(f'desired result: {sum(x[:amount])}')
```